# Can a Facebook app be added as a page tab without being submitted for approval?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

For testing purposes, I'd like to add an app tab to a Facebook fan-page I manage. (From there, I can work out how to create a like gate and similar things.) I looked at Facebook's own [tutorial on the subject](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs).

The part of interest to me is unhelpful because it begins (as far as I can tell) without background: "The Add Page Tab Dialog prompts a person to add an app to a Facebook Page that they admin." There's no explanation for *how to trigger that dialog*.

Do I first need the app approved before Facebook is willing to let me add it? Or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out. It's in the "URI redirect" part. Even though I imagine they *could* provide a link themselves somewhere, it doesn't work like that: you have to enter the link yourself:

https:// www.facebook .com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

removing spaces and replacing the relevant info.